# Drag and Drop imagebutton Dissapears behind different view

Tags: java, android, xml, drag-and-drop, imagebutton

I am programming an android game which users can purchase buildings that are dynamically created once purchased. When they are created, the user can drag and drop them wherever they want to, just as long as it is on the ground. I have the sky and the ground as two different frame layouts, but the sky takes up the top 25% and the ground takes up the bottom 75%. When the user drags the buildings around, they act as they should until the user tries to drag it into the sky area. Instead of it just snapping back to where it was, like I would prefer, it just disappears behind the sky area.

Here is the xml for the top and bottom:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/mars"
    android:id="@+id/gameBackground" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/topHalf" >

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/bottomHalf" >

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/polarCapButton1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:background="@drawable/polarcap" />

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/polarCapButton2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:background="@drawable/polarcap" />

    </FrameLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for the creation of the imagebutton:

```
frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf);
newColonyHut = new ImageButton(runGraphics.this);
newColonyHut.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mainhut);     
newColonyHut.setTag("NewColonyHut");
newColonyHut.setOnTouchListener(new ColonyHutClick());
findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag());
FrameLayout.LayoutParams  param = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
frame.addView(newColonyHut, param);
```

Here is the ColonyHutClick class:

```
public class ColonyHutClick implements OnTouchListener 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());

        String[] mimeTypes = { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN }; 
        ClipData data = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item); 
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v); 

        v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        return false;
    }//end onTouch function
}//end ColonyHutClick class
```

Here is the ColonyHutDrag class:

```
public class ColonyHutDrag extends Activity implements OnDragListener
{

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) 
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                //drag has started
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                //being dragged
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                //stop drag
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                //find drag location
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                if (v == v.findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf))
                {
                    //find position where dropped
                    x = (int) event.getX();
                    y = (int) event.getY();


                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                    group.removeView(view);
                    FrameLayout contain = (FrameLayout) v;
                    contain.addView(view);
                    view.setX(x - (view.getWidth()/2));
                    view.setY(y - (view.getHeight()/2));
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }//end if
                else
                {
                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }//end else
                break;

            default:
                    break;
        }//end switch
        return true;
    }//end onDrag function
}//end ColonyHutDrag class
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup your "Sky" to handle drag events. You can do this with one line:

```
 findViewById(R.id.topHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag());
```

When a dragged object is released over a `View` that doesn't have an `OnDragListener` set, there is nothing to handle the `ACTION_DROP`, and you therefore don't get an opportunity to reset the dragged `View` to `VISIBLE`.

Comment: Why would I need to do that? I don't want the buildings to be able to enter that area at all. If you're right I just want to understand why. Thanks

Comment: When you release a drag over a `View` without a `DragListener`, there's nothing to handle the drop event, so there's no opportunity to make the dragged `View` visible again.

Comment: Did it not work for you? I just tested it successfully. The new line should be added right near the call to `setOnDragListener()` for `bottomHalf`.

Comment: Just got the chance to test it, and it worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No sweat! Glad to help.